# Doctrine 2. orm:schema-tool:update . Set start id

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, fixtures

When I use `./bin/doctrine orm:fixtures:load` to populate tables with sample data first migration sets auto incremental table id like 1,2,3,4,5 etc...

After second `orm:fixtures:load` migration command it purges all data and sets ids like 5,6,7,8,9 and so on...

How can I reset AI id counter to 1 when I load fixtures many times?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`$ app/console help doctrine:fixtures:load`

By default Doctrine Data Fixtures uses DELETE statements to drop the existing rows from
 the database. If you want to use a TRUNCATE statement instead you can use the --purge-with-truncate flag:

```
./app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate
```

Truncate will reset the auto increments.

UPDATE

The console command is for Symfony, but it should be the same using Doctrine only:

```
./bin/doctrine orm:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate
```

UPDATE #2 for the comment about throwing an exception

**If you have foreign keys**, you can only reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` through regular SQL:

```
$connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$connection->exec("ALTER TABLE <tablename> AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;");
```

Comment: Throws exception:

Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint

Answer (score 2):

In Zend 2 I have used below mentioned code to truncate and reset auto incremental value to 1. Use this code in your repository.

```
// To delete all records
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
$queryBuilder->delete();
$queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();

//Reset table auto increment.
$tableName = $this->getClassMetadata()->getTableName();
$connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$connection->exec("ALTER TABLE " . $tableName . " AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;");
```

Comment: i'm lil extend your code, works for simony3:
        $em = $this->container->get("doctrine")->getManager();
        $tableName = $em->getClassMetadata('AcmeWebBundle:NameEntity')->getTableName();
        $connection = $em->getConnection();
        $connection->exec("ALTER TABLE " . $tableName . " AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;");