# setId is ignored for referenced DataFixtures Symfony4 / Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony4, fixtures

I am using DataFixtures to populate my test db with data for unittests.

For entities, which are not using other entities I can set the primary key with setId. For entities, which are used by other entities I can set it, but it is ignored.

E.g. I am setting my users like this:

```
    /** @var Gender $genderW */
    $genderM = $this->getReference(GenderFixtures::TEST_GENDER_W);

    $date = new DateTime('now');
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = new User();
    $user
        ->setId(9)
        ->setFirstName('Hermione')
        ->setLastName('Granger')
        ->setEmail('test9@example.com')
        ->setGender($genderM)
        ->setPassword('odsf3_!45sr-f')
        ->setCreated($date);

    $manager->persist($user);

    $manager->flush();

    $this->addReference(self::TEST_USER_REFERENCE_9, $user);
```

As you see I set the Id for Hermione, but if I do a var_dump in my tests I see that the user Id gets incremented by my number of users for each test I am running. (9, 18, 27....)

The result is that in my tests I have to fetch the users by the unique email address, which is possible, but very annoying:

```
    $userRepo = $this->em->getRepository(User::class);
    $this->user = $userRepo->findOneBy(['email' => 'test9@example.com']);
    var_dump($this->user->getId());
```

Is there a possibility to change this, so I can get my users by Id?

config:

```
"require": {
    "php": "7.2.*",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "cache/predis-adapter": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6.10",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5.11",
    "eightpoints/guzzle-bundle": "~7.3.1",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.4",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.2",
    "snc/redis-bundle": "3.x-dev",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/console": "^4.1",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.1",
    "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.5",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.1",
    "symfony/validator": "^4.1",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "diablomedia/phpunit-pretty-printer": "2.0.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.0",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "*",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.6",
    "sensiolabs/security-checker": "^4.1",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "^4.1",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.5",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.1",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.1"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to create a `setUp` and `tearDown` Method in each class/for your Testsuite.
With these methods you can create/truncate the testdata in your database each time it is run.

According to the Phpunit documentation for [Databasetesting](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.3/database.html#supported-vendors-for-database-testing) the setup will clean up before the test is run

> PHPUnit will execute a TRUNCATE against all the tables you specified to reset their status to empty.

With only a truncate, not resetting the autoincrement values.

To clean your database keys you should use the `tearDown` for the test to reset the keys

> ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

This will reset the autoincrement values after each test.

---

To achieve this only with symfony you could create a command which will do the following things:

1. Reset the testdatabase `./app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --purge-with-truncate` [found this command on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455245/doctrine-2-ormschema-toolupdate-set-start-id)
2. Create fixtures
3. Execute your testrun

You will have 1 command to run your tests only using symfony.

Comment: How would you set that up? We are using doctrine.
I already gave $this->em->getConnection()->beginTransaction(); and $this->em->getConnection()->rollback(); a try, which has not the desired result.

I would not totally want to circumvent doctrine to make this work.

Comment: From what I read I assume the problem is not with phpunit itself. One possible solution could be to write yourself a bash-script (if on linux) to load the fixtures, run the tests and truncate the database after the tests finished.

Comment: I am using  Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture so ideally I would like to have a solution, which does not circumvent the Doctrine Fixture Bundle
My bad.... I added it in the question

Comment: My idea would be to write a shell-script that will truncate the database, loads the fixtures and runs the tests.

Comment: Thank you for asking! Not so far. I would like to avoid doing a bash script and rather rely on internal tools. The bash script would be my last resort if it is even possible to solve it like that.

Comment: Finally back....  So using your solution would still mean, that then the users would accidentally have the ids I give them, because the setter would still be ignored. They would just have them, because they are inserted in a truncated table. So if I switch to users in the datafixture they would have the wrong id again.

Comment: Yes, but why would you like to use the id's anyways? You can get the users data with `$this->getReference(reference_name)` to use use the set inside your fixtures and further can use the e-mail. So I don't see a benefit using the id instead e-mail

Comment: To simplify the use in the tests. If I could call the user by the reference in the unittests that would be fine by me. At the moment I have to fetch them by the email and not by the id, which is needed by most tests.